# Formatting ActiveRecord results for parsing?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, dart

I have a database with entries which I can fetch using ActiveRecord. Currently, using something like `post.to_yaml` yields:

```
 !ruby/object:Post
  concise_attributes:
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: id
    value_before_type_cast: 1
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: user
    value_before_type_cast: efy5qC5YmJNml23JowOUrlmfN0D2
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: content
    value_before_type_cast: bol4
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: location
    value_before_type_cast: '123'
  - !ruby/object:ActiveModel::Attribute::FromDatabase
    name: timestamp
    value_before_type_cast: '12:00'
  new_record: false
```

The exact collection i'm returning is as follow: `record = Post.order(:timestamp).offset(15 * 0).first(15)`

This returned result contains several fields which will be returned to a Flutter application. The data will populate a widget with several fields such as `content`, `date` and `location`, all of which is returned by the above query.

I could use a Dart library to parse the YAML, but is there a better way to condense the returned values so that only the necessary fields are shown?

Comment: Take a look at [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers), they're pretty cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the description shared it seems like you have data from the database and you now need to select only particular fields that needs to be shown.

As per current scenario you could use something like:

```
post.as_json(only: [:content, :name, :location])
```

Else you could modify the query you are using by using select statement for selecting specific attributes from database.

```
Post.select(:name, :content, :location)
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks, but how would i accomplish this if my object is a collection instead? I.e. ```posts = Post.first(15)```, do i simply loop through it using a foreach? Sorry if i did not indicate in the original post.

Comment: I managed to format it as a ```json``` instead which works for my case better, thanks!

Comment: Great...you can use select on ActiveRecord for selecting specific fields as mentioned in the answer as well.